# Google Spreadsheets ImportXML / XPath - Image broken output

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape an image of my website via the ImportXML function in Google Sheets using XPath. The function seems to work, however the output seems to be broken. Instead of getting the URL of the image, I am receiving the following broken output:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 
520 390"%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

I am using the following XPath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'MuiGrid-root-59 jss358 MuiGrid-item-61')]//img/@src
```

I tried several things, but I am bit stuck now. Does anyone know how to deal (and solve) with this encoding error?

*Edit I: hereby also the link to the Google sheet: [example image broken in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1baF3J6ApN5eetFUsKLjiv_NkOnj1l0F4nxNoYvcn6fc/edit#gid=1985969409)*

**Edit II: I've noted that the image is changing, so the above XPath is not working anymore*

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: From your sample value, it seems that the value of `src` is the data URL of SVG. In this case, can I ask you about the value you want to retrieve? By the way, in order to confirm your issue, can you provide the URL?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Hereby the link to the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1baF3J6ApN5eetFUsKLjiv_NkOnj1l0F4nxNoYvcn6fc/edit#gid=1985969409

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot find the value of `images0.ibood.com/686136/large/lg-soundbar-sl8yg-subwoofer.jpg`, that you want to retrieve, at `https://next.ibood.com/nl/nl/electronics`. How about this?

Comment: The same here :-(. The value is gone as the image changes every day. I am rookie and having a hard time to get the value of the image (main product image at ````https://next.ibood.com/nl/nl/electronics````) I want to retrieve back using the right class. 

When using ````//img/@src```` you will see my initial challenge with the encode error ````data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" viewBox=""0 0 
200 100""%3E%3C/svg%3E````. Also added in the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1baF3J6ApN5eetFUsKLjiv_NkOnj1l0F4nxNoYvcn6fc/edit#gid=1985969409.  Any idea?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the HTML of `https://next.ibood.com/nl/nl/electronics`, it seems that the value you want to retrieve is created by Javascript. So, unfortunately, the value cannot be directly retrieved by `IMPORTXML` with a xpath. But I noticed that the value you want is included in the JSON object in HTML. But, unfortunately, the data size is more than 50,000 characters. [Ref](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603) In this case, the value cannot be retrieved by `IMPORTXML`.

So, in this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using a custom function created by Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following scripts to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please put `=SAMPLE1("https://next.ibood.com/nl/nl/electronics")` and `=SAMPLE2("https://next.ibood.com/nl/nl/electronics")` to the cells. By this, the values are retrieved.

```
function SAMPLE1(url) {
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const str = html.match(/<script id=\"__NEXT_DATA__\" type=\"application\/json\">(.+?)<\/script>/);
  if (str.length == 2) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(str[1].trim());
    const value = obj.props.pageProps.initialReduxState.slotItems.mainOffer.imageSrc;
    if (value) {
      return `https:${value}`;
    }
  }
  return "No value";
}

function SAMPLE2(url) {
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const str = html.match(/<script id=\"__NEXT_DATA__\" type=\"application\/json\">(.+?)<\/script>/);
  if (str.length == 2) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(str[1].trim());
    const value = obj.props.pageProps.initialReduxState.slotItems.offers.map(({imageSrc}) => `https:${imageSrc}`);
    if (value.length > 0) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return "No value";
}
```

- In this sample scripts, at first, the HTML is retrieved, and retrieve the JSON object, and return the values from the parsed JSON object.
- When I saw the HTML data, I noticed that there are 2 kinds of the image sources. One is `mainOffer` (This value is obtained by `SAMPLE1()`.). Another is `offer` (This value is obtained by `SAMPLE2()`.). From your question, I thought that you might want the URL of `mainOffer`. But when I checked it by the browser, I noticed that there is the case that the image in the site is different from that of `mainOffer`. I'm not sure about the reason of this. So I proposed 2 patterns.

#### Result:

When above scripts are used, the following results are obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike! The outcome is exactly as expected. The solution and your dedication have motivated me to deep dive more in XPath and Apps Script in the coming weeks :-).  Thanks again for your time and solution!

Comment: @Jesper Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.