# Google sheet web-scrape table within table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, yahoo-finance, custom-function

On this website, https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ANZ.AX/financials - I am trying to extract the value for "Basic EPS" from the 2017 column, into cell J12 (google sheets).

I have the ANZ.AX ticker code in cell C12.

In J12 I have the formula:

```
=EPSGROWTH("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&C12&"/financials")
```

The GROWTH script is where I'm having a problem, as normally the 'xxxx' has been a unique string in the html to match, but in this case it is 'fin-col' which appears everywhere on the page.

```
function EPSGROWTH(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/xxxx.+?>(.+?)</);
  return res && res.length > 1 ? res[1] : "No value";
}
```

Is it because this is a table within a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, how about directly retrieving the values from JSON data which is used with Javascript? This is the related thread. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65386622) When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function EPSGROWTH(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/"annualBasicEPS":(\[.+?])/);
  if (res && res.length > 1) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(res[1]).filter(e => e && e.asOfDate && e.asOfDate.includes("2017"));
    return obj.length > 0 ? obj[0].reportedValue.fmt : "No value"; // or obj[0].reportedValue.raw
  }
  return "No value";
}
```

- In this case, it seems that when `obj[0].reportedValue.raw` is used instead of `obj[0].reportedValue.fmt`, the raw value can be retrieved.

#### Result:

When above modified script is used, it becomes as follows.

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- Related thread

  - [Google Spreadsheets ImportXML / XPath - Image broken output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65364188/7108653)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and effective response, Genius! Now I'll spend sometime trying to understand your solution. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Auckland_Ted Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: if you have the time to respond, what is the best way to learn this stuff for myself? Free resources would be good :) otherwise book recommendations.

Comment: @Auckland_Ted About your new question of `if you have the time to respond, what is the best way to learn this stuff for myself?`, unfortunately, I have no clear information about it. I apologize for my poor skill. For example, in my case, I sometimes answer for various questions in Stackoverflow. I think that this is good study for me. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: No problem, thank you again. I agree this is a great place to learn.